# rxjs: mapping nested observables

Tags: rxjs

I'm struggling with trying to compile this code:

```
this.actions$
    .ofType('ADD_SOURCE')
    .switchMap(
      (action: Action) => {
        var data = <StripeCardTokenData>{
          number: '4242424242424242',
          cvc: '132',
          exp_month: 12,
          exp_year: 2018
        };

        var callback = Observable.bindNodeCallback(Stripe.card.createToken);
        callback(data)
          .map((response: StripeCardTokenResponse) => {
            if (response.error)
              return <Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_FAILED', payload: { code: response.error.code, msg: response.error.message }};
            else
              return <Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_SUCCESS', payload: <CardDTO>{id: response.id, last4: response.card.last4}};
          })
          .catch(_ => {
            return Observable.of(<Action>{ type: 'ADD_SOURCE_FAILED', payload: { }});
          });
      }
    );
```

Typescript is telling me:

> [ts]
>   Argument of type '(action: Action) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Action, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
>     Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

`Stripe.card.createToken` is: [see on here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/555ea54770b8576162e761e344de969d6e960869/stripe/index.d.ts).

`Action` is:

```
export interface Action {
    type: string;
    payload?: any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not return anything from `switchMap`? With `switchMap`, you are suppose to return an observable (apparently an `ObservableInput<{}>`) and here you don;t. `callback(data)....` does not return anything. Maybe you meant `return callback(data)....`?

In any case, this kind of error is really trivial and typescript is good at signalling them. Generally, the error is exactly what it is. So I would advise you to spend time investigating on your own before posting here. You will in fact learn faster.